# How can i change the context path of tika server?

Tags: java, docker, openshift, tika-server

I want to run the [tika server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/tika) in openshift. This works fine out of the box **but** as soon as i run other services at the same time i need a **context path** to determine which service should be addressed in the url.

`https://my-openshift-instance.com/my-first-service`   <- this is a different service working
`https://my-openshift-instance.com/tika-server`        <- this is what i need

In Spring Boot applications you just set something like `server.servlet.context-path=/my-service-name` and it is done. But unfortunately tika server is not based on Spring Boot.

I searched in the official [tika-server docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer), [tika-docker repo](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker) as well as the [normal tika repo](https://github.com/apache/tika) but nowhere was anything documented about context paths.

Comment: Create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource in Open Shift, that's what they made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now I did not find a solution, that works with the official tika server image. To reach my goal, I created a simple Spring Boot MVC application and added the `org.apache.tika:tika-parsers` dependency.

Now I can send multipart requests with an attached InputStream to this service which returns the content type.